# Cookies not being created JS

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

When running my web page the cookies are not being created I have been using IE as I know that chrome does not load cookies on local web pages.

I am loading the JS as

```
<script language="javascript" src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the script to set the cookies which is in the script.js file is

```
function SetCookie(name,val) {

document.cookie = name + "=" + val + ';';

}
```

and in my file for the main page I have set the cookie as shown

```
SetCookie('July',July);
```

When I run the code the cookie is undefined.

Comment: In `SetCookie('July',July);` Is July a variable ?

Comment: @sanA Yes July is a variable

Comment: @Dr.Python then it should work. I tried and it works.

Comment: @sanA Strange, when I try all I get is undefined I've checked and the cookies aren't actually being created for me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a cookie is to assign a string value to the document.cookie object

`document.cookie = "key1=value1;key2=value2;expires=date";`

So, either July has to be a variable or you'll have to pass it as a string.

`var July = 'July';
SetCookie('July', July);`

OR

```
SetCookie('July', 'July');
```